# jquery function recalculate height on click

Tags: jquery, function, height

I have a simple function that calculates the height of a div. I have a font size increaser on my site, and I want to recalculate the height if this is clicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/tSH2L/

```
var boxHeight = function($item) {
        var $this;
        var heightArray = [];
        $item.each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            heightArray.push($(this).height());
        });
        var biggest = Math.max.apply( Math, heightArray );
        $item.parent('div').children($this).css('height', biggest);
    }
    $(function() {
        boxHeight($('.box'));
        $('#fontsize li').on('click', function() {
            boxHeight($('.box'));
        });
    });
```

I need to recalculate the height once the user has clicked on the #fontsize li, and I wanted to make this as simple as possible. Im not sure if you just re call the function but this doesnt work. It may be how this is added to the array

Any help appreciated

Comment: can you use automatic height?

Comment: boxHeight is difficult to understand, can you try re-explain it? just the last line

Comment: I cant, I have three divs with the class of box and I need these to always be the same height, all with different content in. boxHeight basically gets the height of 3 divs with the class of .box, then I get the largest size and append this as a css height value. I basically need to recalculate this when the fontsize li is clicked

Comment: I think I understood, you grow the three boxes height to the tallest of them, right?

Comment: is biggest calculating what you want? can you put a console.log there?

Comment: I think the problem is when I assign a css height the calculation is based on that so it never updates properly

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle or at least post your html and css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tSH2L/

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe try something like this

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hzp3a/)

I didn't debug your code specifically but if I had to guess what was going wrong I'd say you are targeting the wrong element when you try and set the height with this line here,

`$item.parent('div').children($this).css('height', biggest);`

That bit of code won't work me thinks. Try changing it to

`$item.css('height', biggest);`

Comment: your demo looks good, can you add the height before anything is clicked too?

Comment: Yes you can. Set the height with `$().height()` fn. You can use the `boxHeight()` fn to figure out the required height at startup by calling it during the init phase of your script. Something like `$(window).load(function () { var reqHeight = boxHeight(".box"); $(".box").height(reqHeight); });`